# Highcharts multiple pie chart series hover

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to create two pie charts with the same keys but different data in each chart. My options object look like this:

```
const chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Chart One',
      colorByPoint: true,
      size: '50%',
      center: ['25%', '50%'],
      data: [
        {color: '#000000', name: 'One', y: 43},
        {color: '#666666', name: 'Two', y: 12},
        {color: '#cccccc', name: 'Three', y: 54},
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Chart Two',
      colorByPoint: true,
      size: '50%',
      center: ['75%', '50%'],
      data: [
        {color: '#000000', name: 'One', y: 32},
        {color: '#666666', name: 'Two', y: 78},
        {color: '#cccccc', name: 'Three', y: 11},
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

This works almost as expected. But I cannot get one thing working.

On a column chart, when you have multiple series and hover over a point in series A, the corresponding points in the other series will also light up (the other points will dim down). But not in a pie chart. When I hover "Three in "Chart One", "Three" in "Chart Two" is not highlighted.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `mouseOver` callback function you can find the related point and call `setState('hover')` on it:

```
    plotOptions: {
        ...,
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        var relatedPoints = [],
                            series = this.series,
                            pIndex = this.index;

                        series.chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
                            if (s !== series) {
                                relatedPoints.push(s.points[pIndex]);
                            }
                        });

                        relatedPoints.forEach(function(p) {
                            p.setState('hover');
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xm7gc5u6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thanks. Would give this 5 thumbs up if I could!